# How do we check previous command or script executed successfully or not in remote server through shell script

Tags: shell

I would like to write the script to execute the cap commands in the remote server through Jenkins server.

```
ssh -q $username@$server << EOF

cd $CT_PATH && cap -q -s instance=$instance mode=quiet diagnostics:all;
```

I tried this script:

```
echo "command : $? - Successful"

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then

exit 1
 else

echo " continuing next commands"

ls -l

fi
```

which is executed successfully. but if it's failed, the script is looking into another command but I want to stop there if it's failed which means that the script won't be executed further.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `set -e`, which will make the script abort on the first failing unchecked (i.e., not part of `if the_command; then`) command and your first heredoc marker should probably be `'EOF'` instead of `EOF`, unless you want the heredoc interpolated in the context of the host you're ssh-ing from (If really want `EOF`, then you will have to escape the `$`-expansions which should be evaluated on the target host):

```
ssh -q "$username@$server" <<'EOF'
set -e 
cd $CT_PATH #if this or anything else that's unchecked fails, the script will abort because of set -e
cap -q -s instance=$instance mode=quiet diagnostics:all;
#...
EOF
```

Comment: @Ram No need to thank. Just accept/upvote the answer if it's working for you ;-)